# switching between Panels in java applet when deployed on a webpage

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, applet

I am designing an applet and i have made some code which works fine when run in eclipse with the applet viewer.

However, when i try to put it on my web page and the applet has to switch from one panel to another it does not work.. The code looks as follows (this is the part where i try to make it show a new pane).

```
enter code here

package roomBooking;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.lang.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.*;
public class Main extends JApplet {
Connect connection = new Connect();
final LoginScreen login = new LoginScreen();
SessionStorage session = new SessionStorage();
final AdminPanel admin = new AdminPanel();

public Main(){

    final JApplet mainApp = new JApplet();
    add(mainApp);
    mainApp.add(login);


    //handle login
    login.okay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            User newUser = new User(login.username.getText());
            session.setUsersLoggedIn(newUser);
            admin.setWelcome(new JLabel("Welcome "+ newUser.getName()));

            admin.add(admin.getWelcome());
            admin.add(admin.getRoomAdministration());

            if (newUser.getPassword().equals(login.pass.getText()) && newUser.getUserlevel() == 1 ){
                login.setVisible(false);
                admin.setVisible(true);
                mainApp.remove(login);
                mainApp.add(admin); 
                mainApp.revalidate();
                mainApp.repaint();
            }
            else if (newUser.getPassword().equals(login.pass.getText()) && newUser.getUserlevel() == 2){
            }
            else if (newUser.getPassword().equals(login.pass.getText()) && newUser.getUserlevel() == 3){
            }
            else if (newUser.getPassword().equals(login.pass.getText()) && newUser.getUserlevel() == 4){
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane error = new JOptionPane("Wrong username or password");
                error.setVisible(true);
                System.out.println(newUser.getPassword());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example). 2) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 3) For 'switch panels' think `CardLayout`..

Comment: BTW - `public Main(){` should be `@Override public void init(){` for an applet..  **AND** `final JApplet mainApp = new JApplet(); add(mainApp); mainApp.add(login);` should be `add(login);`!

Answer (score 1):

Make life easy. Use a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html)

> A `CardLayout` object is a layout manager for a container. It treats each component in the container as a card. Only one card is visible at a time, and the container acts as a stack of cards.

Basically you will create a main panel to hold all your other panels. Then when you add the panels to the main panel, you give then each a *"name"* to go by

```
LoginScreen login = new LoginScreen();
AdminPanel admin = new AdminPanel();
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

final String LOGIN_SCREEN = "login";
...
CardLayout cardLayuot = new CardLayout();
mainPanel.setLayout(cardLayout);
mainPanel.add(login, LOGIN_SCREEN);
mainPanel.add(admin, ADMIN_SCREEN);
```

When we want to show a different view, we can just call `show` on the `CardLayout`.

```
cardLayout.show(mainPanel, ADMIN_SCREEN);
```

See more explanation and full example at [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)